# Does wait() need synchronization on local variable

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I had this code (which was working fine):

```
public static void runOnUiThread(Activity c, final Runnable action) {
    // Check if we are on the UI Thread
    if (Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper()) {
        // If we are, execute immediately
        action.run();
        return;
    } // Else run the runnable on the UI Thread and wait
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            action.run();
            synchronized (this) {
                this.notify();
            }
        }
    };
    synchronized (r) {
        try {
            c.runOnUiThread(r);
            r.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I was getting `Synchronization on local variable` warning. As suggested, I removed the synchronization on the local variable, in order to fix the warning:

```
public static void runOnUiThread(Activity c, final Runnable action) {
    // Check if we are on the UI Thread
    if (Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper()) {
        // If we are, execute immediately
        action.run();
        return;
    } // Else run the runnable on the UI Thread and wait
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            action.run();
            this.notify();
        }
    }
    try {
        c.runOnUiThread(r);
        r.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And now I am getting an exception when calling this method:

```
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at org.matapps.android.simpleappcreator.Utils$100000007.run(Utils.java:673)
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-15 09:18:13.252 27282 27282 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
```

I'm pretty sure I need the synchronization (as the runnable runs on a different thread), but I was told local variables shouldn't have synchronization. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Both wait and notify must be invoked in a synchronized block

Comment: Have you searched for java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException?

Comment: But I am getting a warning

Comment: add a @SuppressWarnings if it's bothering you

Comment: First you must understand why there is a "synchronization on local variable" warning in the first place. Which is that it's usually a mistake. But in this case, it's not a mistake.

Comment: warning is not necessary a mistake, and here you can ignore it. But your code has another errors: 1)  it may happen that ` r.wait();` executes after `action.run();  this.notify();`, and ` r.wait();`  would wait forever 2) spurious notify may occur and ` r.wait();` returns before `this.notify();`. I suggest to use Semaphore or CountDownLatch instead of synchronized block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Android development tools, but the warning sounds over-zealous.  The compiler is trying to help you to avoid synchronizing on an instance that is only visible to a single thread.  It's smart enough to know that the local variable, `r`, can only be seen by one thread, but apparently it is not smart enough to know that `r` in the original thread and `this` in the new thread both refer to the same instance.

I would try to work around the problem by making `r` an instance variable.

Comment: All I needed to know is that the code is OK, and simply the compiler doesn't know that `runOnUiThread` actually runs the runnable on a different thread... Anyway, I fixed it with a '@SuppressWarnings'. Thanks to anybody who helped!